# How do i send pre formatted Emails using VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, email

How can i send formatted Emails using VB.NET.
I have a Document (MS WORD 2007) which contains text and images
i need to send the contents as an email.
i am able to read the content and place it in the clipboard, however the only functions available with Clipboard class are limiting me to only retrieve the text of the document.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can send email in HTML format, create an HTML file from word, and set it as the body of the Email message. Make sure IsBodyHtml property is set to true.